# Button as Parameter in Swipe Gesture Action in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I just started working with swipe gestures in Swift. I am trying to use them with buttons: an action is supposed to be performed when the user swipes across a button.

In my `viewDidLoad()` of a ViewController-class I got:

```
let leftSwipeButton = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "leftSwipeButtonAction")
leftSwipeButton.direction = .Left

myFirstButton.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeButton)
mySecondButton.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeButton)
myThirdButton.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeButton)
```

`myFirstButton`, `mySecondButton` and `myThirdButton` are buttons (`UIButton`).

And on the same level as `viewDidLoad()` I defined the action:

```
    func leftSwipeButtonAction() {
    // here the .backgroundColor of the button that was swiped is supposed to be set to UIColor.yellowColor()
}
```

As I want to use `leftSwipeButtonAction()` with the same functionality for multiple buttons I do not want to write a function for every single button, but rather pass the `UIButton` that was swiped as a parameter to `leftSwipeButtonAction()`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send only the UITapGestureRecognizer itself as parameter on selector. You have to put : after selector name

```
let leftSwipeButton = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "leftSwipeButtonAction:")

func leftSwipeButtonAction(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //You could access to sender view
    print(recognizer.view?)
}
```